# Xamarin Label Text Appears after moving out of the ContentPage and Moving back to it again

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a string from ContentView

```
public static readonly BindableProperty LabelTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(LabelText), typeof(string), typeof(CustomToolBar), string.Empty);
```

And here is how it is called.

```
<Label Text="{Binding LabelText}" TextColor="#FFFFFF" 
                       FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  
                       FontSize="16" Margin="10,13,0,0" x:Name="LocationName"
                       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation">
                </Label>
```

Here is how it is initiated/used on a contentpage

```
 <local:CustomToolBar CustomImageSource="baseline_arrow_back_black_24.png" 
                                     NavigationBarColor="#FF8800" BorderColor="#FF8800"
                                     CustomBackButtonCommand="{Binding OnBackButtonClicked}" Margin="10,0,0,0" 
                                     LabelText="{Binding SearchedLocationName}"/>
```

The thing is the LabelText is not visible until i move out of the that Page and move back again, that's when the Label appears.

Here is how I bind SearchedLocationName

```
public string _selectedLocation;

        public string SearchedLocationName
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedLocation;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_selectedLocation != value)
                {
                    _selectedLocation = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("SearchedLocationName");
                }
            }
        }


public  void DoSetups(string MainText)
        {
            SearchedLocationName = MainText;
        }
```

Comment: Where do you call DoSetups?

Comment: A calling it on a message listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the code below. Set the value of `LabelText` in `propertyChanged` instead of do the binding in CustomToolBar.

CustomToolBar

Xaml:

```
 <StackLayout>
        <Label  TextColor="Black" 
                   FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  
                   FontSize="16" Margin="10,13,0,0" x:Name="LocationName"
                   LineBreakMode="TailTruncation">
        </Label>
    </StackLayout>
```

Code behind：

```
 public partial class CustomToolBar : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty LabelTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(LabelText),
        typeof(string),
        typeof(CustomToolBar),
        string.Empty,
        BindingMode.TwoWay, 
        null,
        propertyChanged);

    private static void propertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var cView = (CustomToolBar)bindable;
        cView.LocationName.Text = (string)newValue;
    }


    public string LabelText
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(LabelTextProperty);
        set => SetValue(LabelTextProperty, value);
    }


    public CustomToolBar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
     
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
   <local:CustomToolBar LabelText="{Binding SearchedLocationName}"/>
```

Code behind:

```
 public string _selectedLocation;

    public string SearchedLocationName
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedLocation;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedLocation != value)
            {
                _selectedLocation = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SearchedLocationName");
            }
        }
    }

    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SearchedLocationName = "Helo";

        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
```